# Align two divs near each other

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align two divs next to each other and am having some problems with it. I looked up many questions in stack overflow relating to this but nothing seems to help me.

Anyone can see anything wrong with my code? The second div starts off lower down than the first one, and I also want a gap between the two
Thanks in advance

(I tried with and without the vertical align: top)

```css
#parent {
  width: 96%;
}

#Div1 {
  float: left;
  width: 46%;
  left: 1%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  vertical-align: top
}

#Div2 {
  float: left;
  width: 46%;
  left: 49%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  vertical-align: top
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="Div1">some text</div>
  <div id="Div2">some more text</div>
  <br style="clear: both;" />
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried setting the `position: relative` property? Also try adding the `display: inline` property on both divs

Comment: both properties on both divs?

Comment: You don't need floats, but the missing part you needed was `display:inline-block`. Also, you can't set `left` without first setting `position`.

Comment: You should mark an answer as correct my friend. That is one of the purposes of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better use [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) instead of `float: left` `float: right`. Flexbox will make your life much easier!

Now for your question:

```
#parent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

That's it! See how easy was with flexbox?

Comment: You should expand your knowledge and arsenal with flexbox. Its [adopted](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) by all modern browsers. You should also begin to read the new upcoming [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)! Its [not widely adopted yet](http://caniuse.com/#search=grid), but it will be soon...

Comment: @L.Wolf.  If this has solved your problem, please mark it as accepted to stop others from coming to this question to post an answer

Answer (score 0):

Remove the left:% and the parent width%

```
#parent {
}

#Div1 {
  float: left;
  width: 46%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  vertical-align: top
}

#Div2 {
  float: left;
  width: 46%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  vertical-align: top
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pzj7nop6/

Answer (score 0):

Make them both `display: inline-block;`s, remove the `float` and put a `margin-right` on the left one.

```css
#parent {
  width: 96%;
}

#Div1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 46%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#Div2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 46%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="Div1">some text</div>
  <div id="Div2">some more text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Div1 {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   float: left;
   width: 45%;
   border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
   vertical-align: top;
}

#Div2 {
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 45%;
    left: 5%;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. make one common div for block1 and block 2
2. apply css.

### **html:**

```
<div class="main">
<div class="block1">---</div>
<div class="block2">---</div>
</div>
```

### **css:**

```
.main
{
   width:suitable size(block1+block2) in pixel
   margin:0 auto;
}
.block1
{
width:block1_width;
float:left;
}
.block2
{
width:block2_width;
float:right;
}
```